# How do i remove matrix rows that contain all integers?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

Assuming I have a 7x3 matrix which contains both integers and non-integers. What i would want is to remove all rows containing only integers. An example is as follows:

```
A = [1, 1, 2
     2, 1.5, 1
     3, 1.5, 2
     1, 2, 1
     2, 2.5, 1
     3, 2.5, 1
     1, 3, 2];
```

My output should be:

```
B = [2, 1.5, 1
     3, 1.5, 2
     2, 2.5, 1
     3, 2.5, 1];
```

Please, how can I possibly achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
B = A;
B(all(mod(A,1)==0, 2), :) = [];
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this would be to take the [`floor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html) of the matrix and compare this with the original one.  You would thus find those rows that are equal between the two and remove those.

```
B = A;
B(all(floor(B) == B, 2), :) = [];
```

The logic behind this is pretty simple.  `floor` truncates the matrix so that only the whole numbers remain (that is without the decimal point).  You would then element-wise compare this with the original matrix.  Those values that were originally integer would still be integer once you take the `floor` and those elements that are integer would thus give you a `true` result.  Those elements that are floating-point would give you `false`.  We then use [`all`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) to look at each row independently and see if all columns for a row are `true` meaning that the entire row consists of integers.  We would thus find those rows and remove them from the final matrix to produce the desired result.

We thus get:

```
>> format long g;
>> B

B =

                         2                       1.5                         1
                         3                       1.5                         2
                         2                       2.5                         1
                         3                       2.5                         1
```

Comment: Using `==` with floats is pretty risky isn't it? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab), you might be better off putting `B(all(abs(floor(B)-B)<tol, 2), :) = []`; with some tolerance `tol=1e-10` or similar

Comment: @Wolfie If the number was originally integer to begin with, then the comparison should be fine. However, as soon as there is a whiff of floating-point in the number, then we should reject it regardless.  In this case, the tolerance comparison I can get away with not doing.  I would only compare within a tolerance if I am comparing equality with actual floating point numbers, but since we want to determine if a number is actually integer, we can skip. This is one of those times where doing equality actually works out for me, but in general you do compare within a tolerance as you have noted.

Comment: Thanks guys for your time. Both answers look similar but I will pretty much accept the 1st one. I will post just now a revised and more challenging (i would think) version of this question.