# How do i remove matrix rows based on 3 different criteria?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

Assuming I have a 23x3 matrix which contains both integers and non-integers. I would ideally want to remove some of the matrix rows based on the following criteria:

- Remove row if any 2 columns are non-integers
- Remove row if all 3 columns are non-integers
- Remove row if all columns are integers

The above implies that the rows that will be left should have only `one non-integer` and `two integers`

Below is my matrix:

```
    A = [1  1.5 1
         1  2.5 1
         1  3.5 1
         1  1   1.5
         1  1.5 1.5
         1  2   1.5
         1  2.5 1.5
         1  3   1.5
         1  3.5 1.5
         1  4   1.5
         1  1.5 2
         1  2.5 2
         1  3.5 2
         1  1   2.5
         1  1.5 2.5
         1  2   2.5
         1  2.5 2.5
         1  3   2.5
         1  3.5 2.5
         1  4   2.5
         1  1.5 3
         1  2.5 3
         1  3.5 3];
```

My final output should be:

```
B = [1  1.5 1  
     1  2.5 1
     1  3.5 1
     1  1   1.5
     1  2   1.5
     1  3   1.5
     1  4   1.5
     1  1.5 2
     1  2.5 2
     1  3.5 2
     1  1   2.5
     1  2   2.5
     1  3   2.5
     1  4   2.5
     1  1.5 3
     1  2.5 3
     1  3.5 3];
```

I am still learning and still trying to find my feet on which way to go. Please, guys help me out with this one. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how to remove columns according to one criteria? Just do the same, but use the logical "or" (`|`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i remove matrix rows that contain all integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983940/how-do-i-remove-matrix-rows-that-contain-all-integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your three criteria are the same as the one criteria:

- Keep only rows with exactly 1 non-integer

Which, taking inspiration from your (very similar) question yesterday can be done using

```
B = A;
B(sum(mod(B,1)~=0, 2)~=1, :) = [];
```

This does the check for non-integers as seen in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983940/how-do-i-remove-matrix-rows-that-contain-all-integers), then sums across the row to find rows where only one element passed. All other rows are removed.

---

If you actually wanted to implement it as 3 conditions, they can be done (in the order you wrote them) as logical "or" statements separated by a pipe `|`:

```
B = A;
B(sum(mod(B,1)~=0, 2)==2 | sum(mod(B,1)~=0, 2)==3 | sum(mod(B,1)==0, 2)==3, :) = [];
```

Comment: OP might not want to overwrite `A`, although, it is simple to change to `B=A(sum(mod(A,1)~=0,2)==1,:);`.

Comment: @JacobD I was just mimicking the OP's accepted answer from the linked question. I had missed that the answer first assigned `B` as an output matrix, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Wolfie and thanks everyone. One more thing i would have wanted to ask (I know i should probably ask a new question, but i could update this one if need be) is how to obtain a `17x1 matrix` from `B` which has the `count of the rows of B` numbered from `1-17`. Please any ideas how i could try? Thanks once again!

Comment: @User1772 You mean the list of row numbers of `A` which meet your criteria (and are seen in `B`)?

Comment: No! sorry, its just a list of row numbers in B. This has no relationship with A. I just want the rows in B counted. I would need this count to extract the x,y,z coordinate of any of the rows at some point in my code. Sorry about the mix-up. Thank you!

Comment: You can get the number of rows using `numrows = size(B, 1)`, then get a list `1,2,3,...,numrows` using `rownumbers = 1:numrows`.